# m4 stops processing if new value contains hash (#)

Tags: macros, m4

How to force m4 to continue processing line if value has hash?

```
$ echo a a a | m4 -D a=B+
B+ B+ B+
$ echo a a a | m4 -D a=B#
B# a a
```

I want identical behavior for second case - is it possible? (all three occurrences to be replaced).

In my understanding observed behavior is inconsistent and I couldn't find explanation in user manual.

Comment: m4 isn't a tagging system. The character is called "hash".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` character is the first character of a comment and a newline is the last character. The `m4` parses the first `a` and replace it to `B#`. It doesn't scan more because it runs into a comment.

The solution is to change the comment characters with `changecom`:

```
$ echo "changecom(BC,EC)a a a" | m4 -D a=B#
B# B# B#
```

Of course you can choose better comment begin- and end-sequences.

Ps. you can turn off the comment with simple `changecom` without arguments: `echo changecom a a a`. You can read it from manual :)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I worked around the problem for now, but it still looks inconsistent behavior. What if value (which I take from third party), will contain another changecom() ? So far I am getting 'stack overflow' with:  echo "changecom(BC,EC)a a a" | m4 -D 'a=B#changecom(a)' . I will accept the answer though, but I really still don't understand current approach conceptually and how to deal with it.

Comment: I think conceptually comments must be stripped out before processing, but anyway it looks edge case problem and the tool may be useful with workarounds

Comment: It isn't inconsistent behavior, it's well documented. `m4` parses its input and search for known keywords (and macros) and "replace" it to their definition. If you want include a file and don't want to parse, you can use `paste`. Or if it helps, you can use `-P` option to `m4`. Or... If you want to use a tool you should know it :)

Comment: Obviously it does more - it searches not only in input, but recursively in output as well. If I need to replace parameter with path to a file, (which theoretically may contain any character and any keyword) - there is no flag, which will protect my script. I can live with it - but in my understanding m4 should have a flag to disable comment detection in own output. E.g. with cpp preprocessor you just cannot insert new comment into generated output, which I consider more consistent behavior.

Comment: I don't understand you exactly but maybe you want to use the ` and ' characters: in this case `m4` will work with it as a string: include(\`include/foo.bar') will include the file `include/foo.bar`. If you don't want allow to `m4` to processing the included file, use the `paste` macro :)